# Implementing Grid and Ruler for html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with an image editor using JavaScript. It has multiple layers of images similar to Photoshop. How can I have a div of grid on top of all the layers and still be able to click and move the bottom layers? I'm using JQuery-ui for draggable and resizable.

Are there any hacks or workaround for this?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: you can apply pointer-events:none; css to grid div.. so it will pass mouse event.

Comment: I will try it out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pointer-events: none` on the grid/ruler element;

You can find examples [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

Answer (score 0):

It's been long since the question was originally asked but below solution might help for anyone visiting this question for implementing grid overlay for html/JavaScript canvas application.

[Grid Overlay using css](https://css-tricks.com/gridcontrol-a-grid-overlay-system-for-design-development/)

one can easily play with z-index / background color to make element beneath grid overlay clickable.